# Does Residual Sum of Squares always decreases with an additional independent variable?

Tags: residuals, sums-of-squares

^ What the question says. Trying to determine whether this statement is true or false.

Comment: Yes. This is why you usually consider a criterion that also penalizes the number of parameters to avoid overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

If the Res Sum Sq is the criterion that you use to fit your parameters, yes.

You can easily see this by considering that by adding a parameter, Sum Sq cannot be worse, because the simpler model is contained in the more complicated model. So, Res Sum Sq must be equal or smaller.